# Como converto este código de php para javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>


<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> text4  </title>

</head>
<body>

    <?php
/**
 * Converte uma palavra no plural para o singular
 * @param string $str Uma palavra
 * @return string Palavra no singular
 */
function pluraltosingular($str) {
    if (substr($str, -1) != 's')
        return $str;
    // albuns batons marrons
    if (substr($str, -2, 1) == 'n')
        return substr($str, 0, -2) . 'm';
    // flores gizes vezes tenis
    else if (strpos('aeou', substr($str, 0, 1)) === false && substr($str, -2, 1) == 'e' && strpos('nrsz', substr($str, -3, 1)) !== false)
        return substr($str, 0, -2);
    // aneis anzois jornais
    else if (substr($str, -2) == 'is' && strpos('aeiou', substr($str, -3, 1)) !== false)
        return substr($str, 0, -2) . 'l';
    // frances portugues
    else if (substr($str, -2) == 'es' && strpos('clu', substr($str, -3, 1)) !== false)
        return $str;
    // caes paes
    else if (substr($str, -3) == 'aes')
        return substr($str, 0, -2) . 'o';
    // leoes
    else if (substr($str, -3) == 'oes')
        return substr($str, 0, -3) . 'ao';
    // exceto onibus lapis tenis arvores
    else if (strpos('ius', substr($str, -2, 1)) === false && substr($str, -3, 1) != 'n')
        return substr($str, 0, -1);
    return $str;
}
?>



    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Acredito que não tem nada pronto em Javascript para gerar `Sha1`, a não ser que seja uma biblioteca. Qual é a necessidade? Dê mais detalhes na sua pergunta.

Comment: na verdade tinha colocado o código errado  mais já editei obrigado é este agora está correto.

Comment: Creio que a intenção não seja fazer o trabalho por você, sugiro que tente fazer e em cima das suas dúvidas ficará melhor te ajudar.

Comment: estou tentando fazer mais to com duvidas estou aprendendo se tiver uma ajuda de como fazer agradeço não quero que faça para mim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Use as funções correspondentes

PHP `substr` > JavaScript [`substr`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp)

PHP `strpos` > JavaScript [`indexOf`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

PHP operador . > Javascript [operador +](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_operators.asp)

A estrutura do `IF` e os operadores lógicos são os mesmos.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um exemplo para você ver como que faz.. Agora é só seguir a mesma linha..

```js
alert(pluraltosingular("flores"));
function pluraltosingular($str) {
    if ($str.substr($str.length - 1) != 's')
        return $str;
    // albuns batons marrons
    if ($str.substr($str.length - 2,1) == 'n')
        return $str.substr(0,$str.length - 2) + 'm';
    // flores gizes vezes tenis
    else if('aeou'.indexOf($str.substr(0,1)) == -1 && $str.substr($str.length - 2,1) == 'e' && 'nrsz'.indexOf($str.substr($str.length - 3,1)) != -1)
    return $str.substr(0,$str.length - 2)
    /*
    // aneis anzois jornais
    else if (substr($str, -2) == 'is' && strpos('aeiou', substr($str, -3, 1)) !== false)
        return substr($str, 0, -2) . 'l';
    // frances portugues
    else if (substr($str, -2) == 'es' && strpos('clu', substr($str, -3, 1)) !== false)
        return $str;
    // caes paes
    else if (substr($str, -3) == 'aes')
        return substr($str, 0, -2) . 'o';
    // leoes
    else if (substr($str, -3) == 'oes')
        return substr($str, 0, -3) . 'ao';
    // exceto onibus lapis tenis arvores
    else if (strpos('ius', substr($str, -2, 1)) === false && substr($str, -3, 1) != 'n')
        return substr($str, 0, -1);*/
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: obrigado vou tentar

Comment: consegui fazer obrigado a todos que me ajudaram

Comment: marque a resposta que te ajudou para ajudar outras pessoas com o mesmo problema.